# Excel, drop down lists

Tags: microsoft-excel, autocomplete, data-validation

When I created custom drop down lists in excel, my excel sheets don't trim down to a smaller list when I start typing in the drop down list cell.

For example if my drop down list is for USA States [AL...WY] and I type the character 'N' why doesn't my down down list give me a subset of options [...NY...NJ...]. Can subset autocomplete even be done?

Note:
I created my excel drop down lists like so:
http://danielk.org/blog/2009/09/22/excel/

Comment: What kind of dropdown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because that's not how data validation works in excel.  You need to use an active X control.  Refer to the [Contextures data validation page](http://www.contextures.com/excelfiles.html#DataVal) in general and her [ComboBox Data Validation](http://www.contextures.com/DataValCombobox.zip) and [ComboBox Depend](http://www.contextures.com/DataValComboDepend.zip) examples in particular.

**Update**

If you do use her examples, replace the TempCombo_KeyDown event handler with TempCombo_KeyUp.  At least on my excel (excel 2003 SP2) it crashes.

More gory details about the example I pointed you to:

I'm not sure why changing TempCombo_KeyDown to TempCombo_KeyUp works, but it may be related to KeyCode.  MSDN implies that KeyCode is actually a pointer and is for all practical purposes passed by ref, even though the signature says ByVal.  The crash always happens on the End Sub line of TempCombo_KeyDown.

This is just guessing on my part, but by processing the KeyDown event, after the new cell is activated, if it has TempCombo, then the object is activated & can process the KeyUp event.  If the target cell doesn't activate TempCombo, the KeyUp event has no valid object reference and you get a nasty crash.

Comment: Wow MS does make this complex, they should really make this easier in their next version of Excel!