# excel list of values selections to be reduced as you type

Tags: microsoft-excel

what i want is to be able to:

1. i have created a cell with a list of values available for selection (this is ok and can do ok)
2. when i am selecting a value in the above list i would like the list of values to be reduced with matching values as i type....

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been [asked before](https://superuser.com/questions/58514/excel-drop-down-lists/58541#58541) (no accepted answer yet, though).  A data validation drop down can't do this for you. You need to use an active X control, like a Combo box.  This requires a bit of programming.